# Solve $10sin(6x) = 7$ in the interval $0 < x < 90$, solutions go beyond $90$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm to find all solutions to the equation:

$10\sin(6x) = 7$ in the interval $0^\circ <x<90^\circ $.

What I've got so far:

$10sin(6x) = 7 
\iff
x = \begin{cases} 
7.4 + n * 60^\circ  \
\\
22.6 + n * 60^\circ  
\end{cases}$
*where n $\in Z$*

Here, only $0$ and $1$ are possible values for $n$ to get $x$ to remain within the given interval, which gives the solutions:

$x_{1,2,3,4} = \begin{cases} 
7.4^\circ , 67.4^\circ 
\\
22.6^\circ , 82.6^\circ 
\end{cases}$

However, the answer sheet lists the following solutions:
$7.4^\circ , 67.4^\circ , 82.6^\circ , 127.4^\circ , 142.6^\circ $. Also note that $22.6^\circ $ is NOT listed as a solution here, and the solutions go way beyond $90^\circ $, which was the end of the interval. They also answer with 5 values, not identical to mine.

What am I missing? My solving method is obviously incorrect.

Comment: I've never used TEX before, and couldn't find a way to make the degree symbol - any help would be appreciated. I'm also unsure in how many steps of my solving to show, more can of course be presented if needed.

Comment: You can make a degree symbol with ^\circ

Comment: @Arthur Thanks! Updated OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\arcsin(0.7)=44.427$ you know that $6x=44.427+360n$ or $6x=135.573+360n$, hence $x=7.405+60n$ or $x=22.595+60n$.  You'll make it from here.  The values of $x>90$ are clearly wrong answers in the scope of the question.

Comment: My original calculations divided 360 by 6, forgot that when I wrote the answer. Are you sure? Because this is an 'official' exam question from a respected univeristy. I'm not good enough at math to dare say that they're wrong. :-)

Comment: @Zar Sapere aude! For the missing $22.6$ convince the world that it's a solution. For the solution beyond $90$: well, they are greater than $90$, thus not in the scope of our task.  There are exactly four solutions to the given problem.

Comment: Hehe good point. Many thanks for your time, I'll talk to my professor tomorrow and return with the response. (Cannot tag you using @.., by the way)

Comment: My answers were the correct, and he had no idea how those answers came upon that sheet. Many thanks  for your help, once again!

Comment: Congrats!  Please feel free to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that it would be better if
$10sin(6x) = 7 
\iff
x = \begin{cases} 
 7.4+n*360 / 6 \
\\
22.6 + n*360 / 6
\end{cases}$

Comment: Oh, obviously. In my original calculation, I of course divided 360 by 6. Did the math in my head while writing the question. Updated OP, the question still remains, though.